# Why is returning a reference to a string literal a reference to a temporary?

Tags: c++, temporary-objects

A regular string string literal has the following definition:

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred
>   to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array
>   of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as defined below,
>   and has static storage duration (3.7).

I'm assuming because it has static storage duration and that they're typically placed in ROM, it really isn't a big deal if there's a dangling reference to it. The following code emits a warning

```
const char* const & foo()
{
    return "Hello";
}
// warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
```

But this is fine, even without the static keyword

```
const char* const & foo()
{
    const char* const & s = "Hello";
    return s;
}
```

So what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Your code isn't returning a reference to a string literal. It's returning a reference to a pointer. Most of what you cite is irrelevant to the code.

Comment: Where is your cite from? You should add it.

Comment: Why are you returning a reference to a char-pointer instead of the char-pointer itself?

Answer (score 10):

The quote you've posted says that

> A narrow string literal has type “array of n const char”

That is, the type of `"Hello"` is `const char[6]`.

Your code is returning a reference to a `const char *`. This means the array-to-pointer conversion must be applied to the string literal, resulting in a prvalue (= temporary) of type `const char *`. You then bind this to a reference and return that reference. The reference becomes dangling as soon as the function's scope ends and the temporary pointer is destroyed.

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference. In both cases, you return a reference to a pointer that no longer exists.

That the pointee (data) still exists forever is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

```
const char* const & s = "Hello";
```

Here the *variable* is created on the stack...  and *that* variable (which happens to be a pointer) points to a memory location where the string-literal is stored. You're **not** returning the string-literal itself; you're rather returning the reference to the variable will be destroyed soon as a result of stack-unwinding. Hence the returning the reference to such a variable is dangerous, as it is a temporary object.